# How to reach my mopidy server without port?

Tags: raspbian, debian

I just installed the mopidy server on my pi. And everything works fine, I use with web interface, and reach my pi on this ip address: http://192.168.1.105:6680/mopidy/

I installed the avahi-daemon and set the hostname, now I can reach my pi on this address: http://musicbox.local:6680/mopidy/

But I would like to reach without the port, something like this:
http://musicbox.local/mopidy/ or
http://musicbox.local/

What I should do ? Where can I setup?

So I would like to reach the http://musicbox.local:6680/mopidy/ address if I only type the http://musicbox.local/ address.

I use the latest debian wheezy img.

Comment: I've closed this one and reopened the other one since that one is the more general case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think mopidy has some configuration option with regard to the port, but here's the hard way.

Create a file like this:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 6680
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

Call it `iptables.rules` and `su root` (you can't use `sudo` due to redirection):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -F
iptables-restore < iptables.rules
```

If you get a "command not found", you have to install the `iptables` package.  If you get "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name", then the `xt_REDIRECT` module is not available to your kernel (but is by default on raspbian, so this should not be a problem).

If you had previous firewall (iptables) rules set up, you obviously want to integrate this into it.  The configuration above does not really provide an effective firewall (it just forwards the port from the default used for HTTP, 80), but if you didn't have any rules before, then this won't be any different.

If you are also running a web server on the pi, then this will cut it off -- the traffic will be redirected to mopidy instead.  However, you cannot have your cake and eat it too in that case, unless you set up the webserver to redirect certain requests to mopidy.